# What is the alternative of TRUNCATECOLUMNS while inserting instead of copying?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am learning how to use snowflake. As per my understanding TRUNCATECOLUMNS only work for "COPY INTO", is this true? If so what can I use to achieve the same result for "INSERT INTO".

ps. I just want to truncate a column if the size of string is longer than a certain length.

Answer (score 0):

To truncate column [LEFT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/left.html) could be used:

```
CREATE TABLE trg_tab(col_name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO trg_tab(col_name)
SELECT LEFT(col_name, 20)
FROM src_tab;
```

Moreover, there is no performance difference between `VARCHAR(20)` and skipping the size `VARCHAR`.

[VARCHAR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#varchar)

> If no length is specified, the default is the maximum allowed length (16,777,216).
>
> When choosing the maximum length for a VARCHAR column, consider the following:
>
> - Storage: **A column consumes storage for only the amount of actual data stored.** For example, a 1-character string in a VARCHAR(16777216) column only consumes a single character.
> - Performance: **There is no performance difference between using the full-length VARCHAR declaration VARCHAR(16777216) or a smaller length**
> - Tools for working with data: Some BI/ETL tools define the maximum size of the VARCHAR data in storage or in memory. If you know the maximum size for a column, you could limit the size when you add the column.
> - Collation: When you specify a collation for a VARCHAR column, the number of characters that are allowed varies, depending on the number of bytes each character takes and the collation specification of the column.

Comment: Select left works perfectly. Thank you.
Also thank you for letting me know that there is no performance differnece by limiting the VARCHAR size, I assumed that it would have an impact on performance.